# MySQL return an empty results

Tags: java, mysql

hey everyone i have this data in my database 
[image]

and where i try to execute this SQL commande

```
SELECT * FROM `adherent` WHERE nom="arfaoui"
```

it returns this empty results
[image]

can anyone helps me !!!!

Comment: Is there also whitespace in that field?

Comment: no i've make sure there is nothing and iv'e try a million time with different names and same results everytime

Comment: can you get result of `SELECT * FROM adherent`

Comment: yes i can get results when iv execute SELECT * FROM adherent

Comment: Try `TRIM()`. SELECT * FROM `adherent` WHERE TRIM(nom)="arfaoui"

Comment: yeah it works thanks guys <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

`SELECT * FROM adherent WHERE nom=" arfaoui"`

Comment: it work's thanks i find out that i have add a blank space in the end 
a simple mistake can damage a whole program 
thanks <3

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
SELECT nom, LENGTH(nom)
FROM `adherent` 
WHERE nom LIKE "%arfaoui%"
```

It will return that row along with number of characters. That should help finding out whether it contains whitespace or any other characters.

Comment: it work's thanks i find out that whenever i try to add data using java ive add a blank space in the end thanks you've saved me

Comment: you have to accept the answer if that help you @GhassenArfaoui not just say thank you :)

Comment: Sorry @ YCF_L i did not get what you want to say !! .

Comment: @GhassenArfaoui read this to undersatanf more https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work